# jquery match several values for data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm having a bit of difficulty figuring this out,
i basically have the following:

```
<li data-type='filter1 filter2 filter3'>...</li>
<li data-type='filter1 filter2'>...</li>
<li data-type='filter1 filter3'>...</li>
<li data-type='filter2 filter3'>...</li>
```

and a list of checkboxes to filter:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='filter1' /> filter1
<input type='checkbox' value='filter2' /> filter2
<input type='checkbox' value='filter3' /> filter3
```

i want to be able to filter the LI list based on selected checkboxes, so for example, if I selected filter1+filter3 , I would only see  the 1st and 3rd li, 
if i select filter1+filter2+filter3, i would only see the 1st li

i wrote this piece of code, but doesn't seem to do the job since obviously it matches them 1 at a time so starts showing previously hidden ones
thanks!

```
$('.categoriesOnly input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    $('.categoriesOnly input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var filter = $(this);
       $("#category-articles .movie[data-theater*='" + filter.data('theater') + "']" ).show();
        $("#category-articles .movie").not("[data-theater*='" + filter.data('theater') + "']").hide();
}...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems  with your approach. The first main problem is your hide/show will only be based on the last checkbox in your loop of the checkboxes.

The next problem is you are only checking one value at a time, but you need to check for multiple matches.

Following creates an array of  the checked checkbox values, then filters out the LI's that match by creating arrays of each LI "filters" to compare to the array of checkbox values

```
var $checkboxes = $('.categoriesOnly :checkbox').change(function () {
    /* create array of allowed "filters" */
    var allowedFiltersArray = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    /* hide all li then filter matches to show */
    $('li[data-type]').hide().filter(function () {
        /* if no chechboxes checked show all */
        if (!allowedFiltersArray.length) {
            return true
        }
        /* create array of filters for this li */
        var filters = $(this).data('type').split(' ');
        /* can't be a match if length of both arrays is different  */
        if (filters.length !== allowedFiltersArray.length) {
            return false
        }
        /* now do the matching of each array */
        var inValid = $.grep(allowedFiltersArray, function (filterValue) {
            return $.inArray(filterValue, filters) === -1;
        }).length;
        return !inValid
    }).show();

});
```

I assumed that if no checkbozes checked you would want to show all

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xs5x8o8a/)**</kbd>

Comment: hello, thanks this seems a much better approach...never used map before, but seems you are checking for a match on all filters per item, basically i'd like to show the LI for any match (not all of them)

Comment: that conflicts a bit with example you gave

Comment: ah sorry, my bad, actually that worked perfectly...but i removed the full match when u check the length of both arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible in your scenario, but if your filter checkboxes were placed *before* the list items, you could use a combination of **General Sibilings** and **Attribute** selectors.

Then you would get a nice, css-only approach. Something like:

```
li[data-type] {
    display: none;
}

input[value="filter1"]:checked ~ ul li[data-type~="filter1"] {
    display: block;
}

input[value="filter2"]:checked ~ ul li[data-type~="filter2"] {
    display: block;
}

input[value="filter3"]:checked ~ ul li[data-type~="filter3"] {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/02j4vnc3/1/

No JS means a lighter solution! Less headache for you